# Is it possible to get the raw transaction hex of the entire transaction in Brownie?

Tags: ganache, brownie

I am creating unit tests for a smart contract that I am working on using Brownie and pytest. In one of the functions, I need to pass the raw transaction hex of an entire Ethereum transaction (not just the `input` field) to recreate its hash for verification purposes. The transaction I need to pass is a result of calling another method in the same smart contract. So basically:

- Call a method
- Get its raw transaction hex
- Pass it as an argument to another method

I am basically stuck on the second step. The raw transaction hex does not exist in the `TransactionReceipt` object. I can't use static data either as I want to test different scenarios. I am using a local ganache blockchain for the unit tests.

To boil it down, how do I get the raw transaction hex in Brownie?